# Missing CALLs on identifiers_all using PL/SCOPE

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, oracle-sql-developer

Posted this on StackOverflow, but maybe this is the right place for it:
I'm trying to use the view all_identifiers from PL/SCOPE to find out calls to procedures and functions but it's not showing all the calls, some are missing.

I have the following code in a package (PKG_1) at line 4216:

```
tmpParameterId:=  PKG_2.function1(var1, var2, var3);
```

And when I run the query:

```sql
select * from ALL_IDENTIFIERS where  upper(object_name) = 'PKG_1' and line = '4216';
```

I get the following results(owner|name|type|object_name|object_type|usage|line):

```
SYSADM  var3 FORMAL IN  PKG_1 PACKAGE BODY  REFERENCE   4216    
SYSADM  var2 FORMAL IN  PKG_1 PACKAGE BODY  REFERENCE   4216    
SYSADM  var1 FORMAL IN  PKG_1 PACKAGE BODY  REFERENCE   4216    
SYSADM  TMPPARAMETERID  VARIABLE    PKG_1 PACKAGE BODY  ASSIGNMENT  4216
```

And I do not get the CALL usage to function1. I have similar code in other parts of the package and it shows those calls. Really lost here as I cannot tell why some CALLs are being stored in all_identifiers and some are not.